# Python 3 and PyQt 4 recommendations

Tags: pyqt, python-3.x, pyqt4

Is the combination of [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.1/) and [PyQt 4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) recommended? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see why not, there is a [version available](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) for Python 3 which works normally, and the only alternative if you really need Qt would be [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/), which is far from being compatible with Python 3.

Other GUI alternatives would be wxPython ([not in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720806/wxpython-for-python-3-0) yet AFAIK) and the "native" Tkinter (which is something else...).

Answer (score 0):

If PyQt4 is the only non-native module you need, there should be no problem.
Check if all modules you need are available for Py3k!
PyQt4 for Py3k is not yet integrated into all distributions.
I.e. on Debian PyQt4 only works with Python 2 currently.

Have a look at [3to2](http://bitbucket.org/amentajo/lib3to2)! A tool to convert Py3 to Py2 code.
That is just better than coding in Py2 and using 2to3.

Comment: What does *standard Debian* mean, considering that it has 3 main suites (stable, testing, unstable)?

Comment: On lenny/oldstable with Python 2.4 and 2.5
On squeeze/stable with Python 2.5 and 2.6
On wheezy/testing with Python 2.6 and 2.7
On sid/unstable with Python 2.6 and 2.7
As of today on i386 and amd64.