# How to install wxPython for Python 3.3?

Tags: windows-7, wxpython, python-3.3

I need wxPython for a project I'm currently writing. It's a basic text editor- it'll eventually have markdown and bbcode editing supported (with error checking), but right now I want to get the program working. The guide I'm using uses wxPython, but it's official support is only up to 2.5. I'm using Python 3.3, and I grabbed one of the development builds.

I just don't know how to install it, but I found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16165455/2120352), but I'm not sure what it's telling me to do. Is it telling me to create a folder in one of python's subfolders, then use the bit of code in every wx program I make? Or is it telling me something else?

---

**Edit:** I found the site-packages folder and made the folder, then pasted the appropriate folder in the folder I made, but it threw the error :

> ImportError: No module named 'wxversion'

Using `Ninja IDE 2.2`, if it helps at all.

---

**Edit 2:** So I `wx` instead of `wxversion`, and it seemed to work, but now Ninja IDE pulls up `core.py` and tells me

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Does anyone know what this means, and how I can fix it?

Comment: I want to ask the same question: 1) does the newest wxPython (so called "Phonix") support Python 3,3? 2) does the newest wxPython  support ubuntu 13.04? 3)how to download and install it in ubuntu 13.04 if answers to 1) and 2) are yes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have another version of wxPython installed then you don't have any need to use wxversion.  Just put Phoenix's wx package folder directly in site-packages and use it normally.

Comment: So what do I call? Just wx, like normal?

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to go

Comment: OK, calling wx alone worked, but I get the error 'ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.' (See edit 2 in original post)